# Changing Model Name Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my first day with Laravel. I made a model previously named `Title` and just before I migrated it I decided to change the name to `Blog`, and In doing so I changed the migration file to `create_blogs_table` I also changed the model class and the filename to "Blog" and I migrated it with no problem. However when I ran tinker and I tried to do the simple `Blog::all()` it gave this error

```
PHP Error:  Class "Blog" not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

and when I ran `Title::all()` it gave me this error

```
[!] Aliasing 'Title' to 'App\Models\Title' for this Tinker session.
<warning>PHP Warning:  include(C:\coding\laravel\laravelcwd\vendor\composer/../../app/Models/Title.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\coding\laravel\laravelcwd\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 571</warning>
<warning>PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'C:\coding\laravel\laravelcwd\vendor\composer/../../app/Models/Title.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\coding\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\coding\laravel\laravelcwd\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 571</warning>
<warning>PHP Warning:  Class "App\Models\Title" not found in C:\coding\laravel\laravelcwd\vendor\laravel\tinker\src\ClassAliasAutoloader.php on line 109</warning>
PHP Error:  Class "Title" not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

My assumption would be that I didn't change the namespace somewhere in the project. So I checked my models file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Can someone please drop an explanation for this it would be really appreciated thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to run `composer dump-autoload` in your terminal at the root of the project

Comment: what laravel version?

Comment: did you rename the file also ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the command `composer dump-autoload` in your terminal at the root of the project.

This command regenerates the list of all the classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php).